# Programmatically HotBoot (Hot Reboot) Android Device

Tags: android, reboot, root

I'm currently using this code to Reboot my Android Device:

```
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot" });
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, I want to `HotBoot (or "Hot Reboot")` my Android Phone using Java. Does anyone know a way to do this?

*(If you don't know what HotBoot is, [refer to this link](http://www.droidxforums.com/forum/droid-x-hacks/35451-what-hot-boot.html))*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a rooted phone. (Just in case)

```
su
busybox killall system_server
```

Or with your code

```
try {
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
            .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "busybox killall system_server"});
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```